# c#. MSMQ .The max size of a single message

Tags: c#, size, message, msmq

Using **msmq** I want to send a message (***near 1 GB***). I want to send *array of bytes*. But I can send only **4 MB**. **How** can I get around this limitation ?

Comment: A limit has always been part of MSMQ.  Perhaps you should look at another package.

Comment: Yeah. "Reading the documentation" and "learning the tools you use" are concepts worth discussing. The 4mb limit is fundamental to MSMQ for a long time - it is not a file store.

Comment: http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/how-increase-size-msmq-drive

Comment: Updated URL: https://vox.veritas.com/t5/Enterprise-Vault/How-to-increase-size-of-MSMQ-drive/td-p/294067

Answer (score 18):

As you know the maximum size of a message in MSMQ is 4Mb, its better to go for some other solutions.

**Solution :**
  If you want to transfer data that exceeds this size, you will have to cut it
into chunks in the sender's side, and recombine it in the receiver side.

**Why is there a 4MB limit on MSMQ messages?**
  Check out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/08/22/why-is-there-a-4mb-limit-on-msmq-messages.aspx) blog.

**How to send files larger than 4 MB by using Microsoft Message Queuing** ?   [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198686/en-us)

Comment: in the process of testing, I found this size  (4 MB)

Comment: Yup. Try Split data into server parts, each < 4MB and combine them at the destination.

Comment: @ Zhenia : Limit your byte arrays by under 4 MB each on sender's side and combine them at the destination.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have to stick to pure MSMQ? If you might consider switching to [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/), it has a feature called [DataBus](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/894156-attachments-databus-sample) which can effectively place a large payload outside of MSMQ, but ties the payload to an MSMQ message.

(It also, in my experience, makes working with MSMQ far more pleasant from C#. But YMMV)

---

If you can't use NServiceBus, you could at least be inspired by it. Generate a random file name, store the content on a share accessible to both endpoints, include the file name in your message.