# Using WCF with MSMQ binding: How can I handle soap messages that exceed MSMQs 4MB message limit?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, msmq, msmq-wcf

We have an integration scenario where we have to call a WCF service using an MSMQ queue (using WCFs netMsmqBinding).

If I understand correctly, MSMQ has a 4MB limit on message size.

So my question is: How do the WCF/MSMQ bits handle SOAP messages that exceed this limit? Is there for instance some functionality that splits large SOAP response bodies?

Note that I'm not asking only about MSMQ message size limitations, judging from other answers and MSMQ docs, the limit seems to be 4 MB. I wonder if the WCF MSMQ binding works around this limit somehow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c#. MSMQ .The max size of a single message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332080/c-msmq-the-max-size-of-a-single-message)